# Spring Integration : How can chain jms and jdbc outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc, spring-jms

I want to do some treatment and send message to my broker if its ok, I want to make an Insert to database.

I try with jms outbound channel adapter and jdbc outbound channel adapter but i dont find solution.

How can i do it with spring integration ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<recipient-list-router/>` to send a message to multiple channel adapters. Or...

Make the final channel a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`; do not add a task executor to the channel.

Set the `input-channel` of the jms outbound adapter to that channel; set `order="1"`.

Set the `input-channel` of the jdbc outbound adapter to that channel; set `order="2"`.

By default, subscribers to pub/sub channels are called in order as long as none throw an exception, in which case subscribers after the failure are not called.

They will actually be called in the order they are declared, but I prefer to make the order clear with the `order` attribute.